# How to reconnect when a WebSocket disconnects?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Example:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/', {protocolVersion: 8, origin: 'http://websocket.org'});
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('connected');
    ws.send(Date.now().toString(), {mask: true});
});
ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('disconnected');
    // What do I do here to reconnect?
});
```

What should I do when the socket closes to reconnect to the server?

Comment: If I remember correctly sockets try to reconnect upon disconnection

Comment: @SterlingArcher unfortunately, it does not actually do that

Comment: A robust solution isn't too terrible but it's not exactly a 5 line patch either. Here's one solution. https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket/blob/master/reconnecting-websocket.js#L124

Comment: @aembke: joewalnes' project has been [abandoned](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket/issues) for over a year and it's unclear if it targets node or the browser.

Comment: Duplicate of [NodeJS Websocket how to reconnect when server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691996/nodejs-websocket-how-to-reconnect-when-server-restarts)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all your setup in a function and then call it from the close handler:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var openWebSocket = function() {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/', {protocolVersion: 8, origin: 'http://websocket.org'});
    ws.on('open', function() {
        console.log('connected');
        ws.send(Date.now().toString(), {mask: true});
    });
    ws.on('close', function() {
        console.log('disconnected');
        openWebSocket();
    });
}
openWebSocket();
```

However, there is likely more logic you want here (what if the `close` was on purpose?  what happens if you try to send a message while its reconnecting?).  You're probably better off using a library.  [This library](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) suggested by aembke in the comments seems reasonable.  [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is not a bad choice (and it gives you non-WebSocket transports).