# At what frequency of updates do WebSockets become more efficient than longpolling?

Tags: http, websocket, scaling, cost-management

I'm working on a project, and I'm trying to decide whether to use WebSockets or longpolling.

This brings up an interesting question: what is the breakeven point between using WebSockets instead of traditional HTTP techniques? Clearly, if you need daily updates, http requests are better, but for real-time updates, WebSockets would be better. (I think. Correct me if I'm wrong!)

Let me be more specific: 
Assume that for a good user experience a web app requires a user to be updated in a period of time *P*.

Additionally, assume that we are only using WebSockets to send updates from the server to the client, and that the average JSON object sent looks like this ( I'm including this because I imagine average data size matters):

```
{ 'animal' : 'dog',
  'people_who_have_petted'  : ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Thomas'], 
  'people_who_like' : ['Tom', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Thomas','John', 'Mary'], 
  'people_who_dislike' : ['Jerry','Cat', 'Banker'] 
  'user_voted_phrase' : "Dogs are a man's best friend!"
}
```

In your experience, at around (no need to be extremely precise) what period *P* would it make more sense to use WebSockets instead of traditional http techniques for scaling and cost purposes?

Comment: I'd suggest you read this post which discussed when ajax is preferred and when websocket is preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204720/mojolicious-should-i-use-one-websocket-or-several/28206740#28206740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right decision depends on lot of factors, not only the refresh intervals.

[Hard downsides of long polling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676324/hard-downsides-of-long-polling)

[WebSocket/REST: Client connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145970/websocket-rest-client-connections)

On my experience, I would not use long polling unless there is a big reason or just the data push feature of my application is very dull.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer in the second link really answered my question. For my purposes, I think I'll use a mix of REST and web sockets like you describe.