# How to reconnect with isomorphic-ws?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm using `isomorphic-ws` for a WebSockets client. When my server disconnects or the connection drops, it doesn't reconnect. When searching for a solution to reconnect it, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691996/nodejs-websocket-how-to-reconnect-when-server-restarts) simply suggests using `ws-reconnect`. This isn't possible since I'm not using `ws`, but `isomorphic-ws`. What is the proper way to reconnect with `isomorphic-ws`?

Comment: hey, were you ever able to do it? I'm having the same issue now

Comment: No. (character limit)

Comment: that's encouraging...